# Dynamic Data Display Isoline white edges

Tags: c#, wpf, graph, dynamic-data-display

I've got a graph that looks like this:
[image: Graph]

And I want it to look like this:
[image]

I've been using Dynamic Data Display's Isoline library for this.

The issue is that in the upper-right corner, the area is colored, even though all values in that area are 0 (hence why the isolines stop).
Does anyone know if there is a way I can adapt my .xaml file so that area will just display a white background color?

Thank you in advance,

CX

My current .xaml file looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="IntensityChart.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d3="http://research.microsoft.com/DynamicDataDisplay/1.0"
    Title="DynamicDataDisplay Sample - Intensity Chart" WindowState="Maximized"
    Icon="{x:Static d3:D3IconHelper.DynamicDataDisplayWhiteIcon}">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <d3:ChartPlotter Name="plotter" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
        <d3:ViewportHostPanel>
            <Image Name="image" d3:ViewportPanel.ViewportBounds="0,0,2,1.5" Stretch="Fill"/>
        </d3:ViewportHostPanel>

        <d3:IsolineGraph Name="isolineGraph"/>
        <d3:IsolineTrackingGraph Name="trackingGraph"/>
        <d3:CursorCoordinateGraph/>

        <d3:CursorCoordinateGraph/>
        <d3:AxisCursorGraph/>
    </d3:ChartPlotter>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's empty? the blue top right indiciates that it isn't?

Comment: Hi i am going to develop a isoline graph like the one you have but cant figure out how to do it :) Can you post your code xaml and c#? :)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have the code any more, but if I recall there was plenty of example code available on their site. You should be able to copy/paste most of it. If you want, I can ask the guy who implemented that part if he remembers anything important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't worked much with Isolines, but based on the information I DO know about it, it looks like you'll have to change the palette class you use for your graph. There is a discussion that outlines a solution on the D3 discussion board.

[Discussion](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/discussions/236973)

You could take the advice there and create a ratio based on your data, or you could just get to the source and in your palette class, tell all 0 values to be coloured with white.